# Minitest/Capybara: Green test turns red when switching to JS driver

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I have a green test:

```
test "study page & question screen" do
    assert_title "Study | Word Up"
    assert page.has_selector?('h3', text: "STUDY"), "Panel title missing or wrong"
    assert page.has_selector?("div.progress-bar"), "Progress bar missing or with wrong class"
end


16:24:23 - INFO - Running: test/integration/study/study_test.rb
Started

StudyTest
test_answer_screen                                              PASS (0.98s)
test_study_page_&_question_screen                               PASS (0.27s)

Finished in 1.26314s
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

As I have a lot of (on-page) Javascript code on the same page that I also want to test. Therefore I tell Capybara to use a driver capable of Javascript. For example webkit, but I've tried poltergeist and selenium as well.

```
test "study page & question screen" do

    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
    assert_title "Study | Word Up"
    assert page.has_selector?('h3', text: "STUDY"), "Panel title missing or wrong"
    assert page.has_selector?("div.progress-bar"), "Progress bar missing or with wrong class"
end
```

Suddenly the test is red. Although I haven't done anything else but changing the driver.

```
16:28:21 - INFO - Running: test/integration/study/study_test.rb
Started

StudyTest
test_answer_screen                                              PASS (1.12s)
test_study_page_&_question_screen                              ERROR (5.11s)
Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:         Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: expected "" to include "Study | Word Up"
```

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, I think you're visiting the root path in a setup method.  So your test visits the root path, and then the Capybara driver is changed.  Try changing the driver and THEN visiting the root path.

Basically, add

```
visit root_path
```

after

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
```

This fails:

```
setup do
    visit root_path
end

test "study page & question screen" do
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
    assert_title "Study | Word Up"
end
```

This passes:

```
setup do
end

test "study page & question screen" do
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
    visit root_path
    assert_title "Study | Word Up"
end
```

Comment: This is exactly right -- If you change the driver after already visiting the page then you are creating a new Capybara session which has none of the info about the page you opened in a different session.